# more than values will display by only selected slicer in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, slicers

I'm working on designing a dashboard in power bi. I want a user click on the slicer by name of project title.

For example, the user click project A in the slicer.  As a result, the table will show that project A's progress for all months (Jan-Dec). Otherwise, if the user is not clicking the slicer, the table remains blank. how I'm supposed to do?

Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HFIp.png)

Answer (score 0):

As basic functionality of a slicer, if nothing is selected means all values are selected. You can now go for 2 options as stated below-

**Option-1:** Make the Slicer **Single Selection** enable from the properties. This case one value will be always selected in the slicer and the result will be there for the selected value. This will decrease the confusion you are looking to solve.

**Option-2:** create a measure that returns 1 or 0 for each row based on the Slicer value selection. Then Hide all values having 0 in the measure. Logic for that measure will be - if 1 value is selected in the slicer, return 1. For all other case return 0.

Comment: thank you Mr mkRabbani. I do not understand for solution option 2. how is that possible?

Comment: You can create a Measure based on values selected in the Slicer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do with the new feature of Field Parameters (check in Preview features):

1. Create a Column Called None with all blank values of ""
2. Create a Field Parameter to select None field as well as the other fields you want (this lets you combine the fields together into 1 Slicer).
3. Make Field Parameter into a Slicer.
4. Now you will have a Slicer with None option that will give a blank result.  Select for this as the default to not show any results.  Save the dashboard in this state to keep the selection this way.  You can select the other fields to populate data.

[image]